# Why click tree throws 'System.Windows.Documents.Run' is not a Visual or Visual3D' InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree, visualtreehelper

Sometimes right-clicking treeviewitem results unhandled InvalidOperationException. In code behind I select the right clicked row:

```
    static TreeViewItem VisualUpwardSearch(DependencyObject source)
    {
        while (source != null && !(source is TreeViewItem))
            source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        return source as TreeViewItem;
    }

    private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

            if (treeViewItem != null)
            {
                treeViewItem.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
    }
```

According to stacktrace above is the source of the problem.

xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ClassesItemsSource}" DataType="{x:Type pnls:FavoriteObjectTableViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="{Binding Bitmap}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding TableName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pnls:FavoriteObjectClassViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Bitmap, Converter={StaticResource UriToCachedImageConverter}}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding ClassName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView Name="Insert_ObjectTreeIE" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TablesItemsSource}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown"></EventSetter>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnMouseDoubleClick" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Stacktrace:

```
e.StackTrace    "   at MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsVisual(DependencyObject element, Visual& visual, Visual3D& visual3D)\r\n   
at MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsNonNullVisual(DependencyObject element, Visual& visual, Visual3D& visual3D)\r\n
at System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)\r\n   
at Tekla.Nis.Application.Shared.UI.Panels.FavoriteObjectsView.VisualUpwardSearch(DependencyObject source) in c:\\XXX\\161wpf\\src\\SharedAppFeature\\Panels\\FavoriteObjectsView.xaml.cs:line 45\r\n   
at Application.Shared.UI.Panels.FavoriteObjectsView.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) in c:\\XXX\\161wpf\\src\\NisSharedAppFeature\\Panels\\FavoriteObjectsView.xaml.cs:line 52\r\n   
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)\r\n   
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)\r\n   
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)\r\n   
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)\r\n   
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)\r\n   
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnPreviewMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)\r\n   
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)\r\n   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)\r\n   
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)\r\n  
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)\r\n   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n  
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Application.Run()\r\n   at "my application start location"
```

I can reproduce this only sometimes. My colleague said left click item 1 and right click item 2 produces this every time in certain tree.

Comment: A `Run` is no Visual and would need separate handling. does `VisualUpwardSearch(e.Source as DependencyObject);` already fix it for you? Also: to reproduce the click must happen on the Label not the image!

Comment: i click on textblock, not image but now i been clicking for minutes and can't reproduce it. so I don't know if this change makes a difference.

Comment: plus changing it to e.Source results the item parent being selected

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The issues reproduces when you click somewhere in the Label's text. In this case the `e.OriginalSource` will be a `Run` object which is a part of internal composition of the `Label` or `TextBox`. The `Run`element is not inheriting from a `Visual` class, thus can't be a part of the visual tree, in this case the `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);` will throw `InvalidOperationException`.

The easiest solution will be to make each text control (`Label` in your case) `IsHitTestVisible="False"`, this will exclude these controls from hit testing logic, which means that it will never be the `e.OriginalSource` of an event, instead it's parent will be picked up and most likely the parent will be a `Visual` element.

Comment: thanks! thorough testing will tell if this fixes it. for me it was nearly impossible to reproduce. in 1h of clicking I managed to get the exception 2 times. +1 for explanation. can you tell me about 'most likely part'? so this can happen even if I set IsHitTestVisible="False"?

Comment: so additional check "if (source is Visual)" could be added just to be on the safe side?

Comment: No, don't bother with the check, it may mask future problems, I mentioned that it will be "most likely a Visual" because there can be cases if you add other text elements to your templates without setting IsHitTestVisible to false. In your case it is 100% safe, you may want to put the IsHitTestVisible only on the root StackPanel of your templates to avoid the problem with other text elements in the template.

Comment: thanks. my colleague tested and couldn't reproduce anymore. strange bug/feature because it was so difficcult tgo reproduce.

Comment: I faced the same problem for Run within TextBlock, I set whole TextBlock to IsHitTestVisible="False" problem disappeared. Thanx!!!

Answer (score 6):

I found that starting the search with the parent worked in my case.  My TreeViewItem text consisted of several runs so I couldn't disable hit test.

```
    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeViewItem;
        if (e.OriginalSource is System.Windows.Documents.Run)
            treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(((System.Windows.Documents.Run)e.OriginalSource).Parent as DependencyObject);
        else treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

        if (treeViewItem != null)
        {
            treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. The workaround IsHitTestVisible="False" did not fix my problem => it happened that the context menu was not popped up anymore after right-click.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. Instead of fixing all the places in XAML where this might occur, you just fix VisualUpwardSearch (or whatever your equivalent) -- the first thing it should do is see if the DependencyObject is a Run, and if so, start with its Parent.